# add background image in a android graphview

Tags: java, android, android-graphview

```
package com.example.graph;                                     

public class MainActivity extends Activity                        
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                          
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                  

        GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[]{
                new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d)
                , new GraphViewData(2, 1.5d)
                , new GraphViewData(3, 2.5d)
                , new GraphViewData(4, 1.0d)
            });

        GraphView graphView = new BarGraphView(MainActivity.this,"GraphViewDemo");
        graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries);
        graphView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
        graphView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(50, 50, 0, 200));        
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what you are actually trying to add in your graphView?

Comment: i just want an image behind the graph view or graphsheet

Answer (score 0):

You can use an image for the background in graphview by setting the graphView.setBackground property, but Android will complain if your minimum API is less than 16.

```
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/output_background", null, getPackageName());
Drawable graph_background = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
graphView.setBackground(graph_background);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is stack the graph on top of an ImageView. So if you're adding your GraphView to a FrameLayout, have that FrameLayout already contain an ImageView displaying your image.